# How to access Python class in another folder when building Django management command?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to turn a Python script into a Django management command. My script is in an application folder called sites. Folder structure:

```
project
|--sites
   |scanner.py
   |--management
      |__init__.py
      |--commands
         |__init__.py
         |getdeals.py
```

I'm trying to have getdeals.py run as a management command. It finds objects in my Site model and then uses them to create an instance of the SiteDeals class, which is in the scanner.py file.

getdeals.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from sites.models import Site


class Command(BaseCommand):

    help = "Scans all sites for deals"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        site_set = Site.objects.all()

        for site in site_set:
            scraper = SiteDeals(site)
```

When I run `python manage.py getdeals` it says `NameError: name 'SiteDeals' is not defined`.

I thought of taking the code from `handle` and writing it as a main() function in scanner.py, and then accessing it from getdeals.py, but can't work out how to access it that way.

How do I access SiteDeals from the scanner.py file, given that it is in another folder from my management/commands folder, so that I can pass my objects to it?

Comment: IMHO you'd need to import `SiteDeals` too in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `SiteDeals`, just as you import the `Site` model. Try:

```
from sites.scanner import SiteDeals
```